# php mysql dynamic table display with numbring

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have page where i populate table from mysql using php. I have 10 tables. 
If there is no data in table then the table is not displayed.

i have displayed numbering like "1" for table one 2 for table 2 and so on . now if table 3,6,9 have no data then page will display table of numbers 1,2,4,5,7,8,10. but i want that numbring according to the number of tables displayed.

```
$tbl2= "SELECT * FROM wp_health_aanvullend_moduliar WHERE health_id=$hid";
$rs2 = mysql_query($tbl2);
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($rs2);

 <?php if($count2 > 0){?>

<table class="sub_front_efect" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" border:none; margin:10px 0;">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="100%" class="health_sub_front">Aanvullend moduliar</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php  $wp_health_aanvullend_moduliar = "wp_health_aanvullend_moduliar";
             $crows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wp_health_aanvullend_moduliar WHERE health_id=$hid");
              foreach ($crows as $crow) {
                 $type          = $crow->type ;
                 $price         = $crow->price;


              ?>
    <tr data-price="<?php echo $price; ?>"><td width="65%"><?php echo $type; ?></td><td style="border-right:1px solid #ccc;">&euro; <?php echo $price; ?></td></tr>
    <?php 
              }
    ?>
  </tbody>
```

```
<?php } ?>
```

if all the table has data then all displayed.[image: tables with numbers]
what can be the logic

thanks

Comment: its 700 lines code . how can i paste here.

http://jazeker.net/zorgverzekering/Menzis%20ZorgVerzorgd/

chekc it

Comment: i have class on each table ".table_front" and used $(".table_front").length() to count the number of tables . but how can make numbing for tables dynamically. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a counter inside the loop where you displaying the tables. In all tables without content the counter wouldn't be increase.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Something like this:**

```
$k=1;
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
$query="select * from table".$i."";
$result=mysql_query($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count>0)
{
echo"<table>";
echo"<tr><td>Table".$k."</td></tr>";
echo"</table>
$k++;
}

}
```